# Force text to wrap onto 2 lines

Tags: swiftui, word-wrap

I am trying to force text to wrap onto 2 lines, even if there is space available to show it on a single line.

For example:

"This example" would show as:

> This
> example

and only occupy the space of the longest line (in this case the word example).

"And with four words" would show as:

> And with
> four words

I don't want to hard code line breaks in the strings.

In Jetpack compose I can use `Modifier.width(intrinsicSize.min)` which asks the view to draw itself as narrow as possible, and when combined with a lineLimit gives me what I need. I'm trying to find the equivalent for SwiftUI.

At the moment all I can think of is to find the space character closest to the center of the string, and replace it with a line break, but that seems overly cumbersome, and may not work well with non English languages / non Latin characters. I'd rather do it with layout if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift UI, you can use the `.frame()` modifier to explicitly set a fixed width for the text, forcing it to wrap onto multiple lines if needed along with `.lineLimit(2)`

Comment: But I don't want to explicitly set a fixed width. I want the width to dynamically grow, but with text occupying 2 lines instead of one. My options seem to be: single line text with dynamic width, or fixed width with dynamic height. I cannot see anyway to achieve a fixed height that is more than one line (with text occupying multiple lines) and dynamic width.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use an overlay with slightly less width than the width needed. The width needed (and the height needed) can be established in the base view by displaying the text hidden:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var theText: Text {
        Text("This example")
//        Text("And with four words")
    }

    var body: some View {
        (
            theText + Text("\n") + theText
        )
        .lineLimit(2)
//        .frame(width: 100)
        .hidden()
        .overlay {
            theText
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.trailing, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- This approach allocates more width than is needed, because the base view is built from the full text on one line. However, you can apply a frame width if you know the size that should be sufficient (as long as you make it smaller and not larger). This causes truncation in the base view, but it's hidden so it doesn't matter.
- You could also use a VStack to build the base view, instead of Text concatenation, but I reckoned the spacing was more likely to be correct if you built the base view using pure Text.
- If you would prefer that the 2-line overlay is left-aligned with the base view then just apply .leading alignment to the overlay.